# Hide div when is empty and add class to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have on the product price and sale price

Both classes have width: 50% and inline-block.

I want to write a script that changes style (add class for width 100% and change font style) to the price when there is no sale price.

This is what I tried so far.

This is first code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 if( $('.eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28').html().trim().length === 0) {
     $('.eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28').hide();
     $('.eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-24').addClass('change_regular_price');
 }
});
```

This is second code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 if( $('.eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28').is(':empty')) {
    $('.eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28').hide();
    $('.eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-24').addClass('change_regular_price');
 }
});
```

And also doesn't work because is hiding sale price on all product (also products with sale price )

HTML is:

```
<div class="price_div">   
 <div class="esg-content eg-post-903 eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28-a">
   <a class="eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28 eg-post-903"  href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self">regular_price 1.200 €</a></div>

<div class="esg-content eg-post-903 eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-24-a">
  <a class="eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-24 eg-post-903"   href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self">sale_price 1.100 €</a></div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use DOM traversal to find the `.regular_price` related to the `.sale_price`. We can show you how to do that, but we need to see your HTML. Could you please edit your question to include it

Comment: Here it depend on the structuring of your .sale_price if the price with in certain HTML tag then use find() then check the value if it is only text with in that class without any tag then use text() and check it with if text==''

Comment: post some jsfiddle(or else) at least

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through every price_div, and find the regular and sale pairs inside of that and then you could update them independent of other price divs. something line:

```
$(".price_div").each(function(_ix, el) {
  var $priceDiv = $(el):
  var $regularPrice = $priceDiv.find(".eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28");
  var $salePrice = $priceDiv.find(".eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-24");

  if( $regularPrice.is(':empty')) {
    $regularPrice.hide();
    $salePrice.addClass('change_regular_price');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to select the empty sale_price items with $('.sale_price:empty') and then loop through the results by adding a .each()

```js
$('.sale_price:empty').each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parent().find('.regular_price').addClass('change_regular_price');
})
```

```css
.sale_price {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.regular_price {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

.regular_price.change_regular_price {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class='sale_price'>
      $5.00
    </div>
    <div class='regular_price'>
      $7.00
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='sale_price'></div>
    <div class='regular_price'>
      $8.00
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='sale_price'>
      $15.00
    </div>
    <div class='regular_price'>
      $17.00
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, only class doesn't add to regular price:/

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $( ".price_div" ).each(function() {
    var regular_price = $(this).find('div:first-child');
    var sale_price = $(this).find('div:last-child');
    if( sale_price.find('a').html().trim().length === 0) {
      sale_price.hide();
      regular_price.addClass('change_regular_price');
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
.price_div {
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          width: 600px;
          height: 40px;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        .price_div div {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 50%;
          height: 40px;
          line-height: 40px;
          float: left;
          text-align: center;
        }
        .change_regular_price {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price_div">   
  <div class="esg-content eg-post-903 eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28-a">
    <a class="eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28 eg-post-903" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self">regular_price 1.200 €</a>
  </div>
  <div class="esg-content eg-post-903 eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-24-a">
    <a class="eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-24 eg-post-903" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self">sale_price 1.100 €</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="price_div">   
  <div class="esg-content eg-post-903 eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28-a">
    <a class="eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-28 eg-post-903" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self">regular_price 1.200 €</a>
  </div>
  <div class="esg-content eg-post-903 eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-24-a">
    <a class="eg-top-ponudbe-content-element-24 eg-post-903" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```